ipadOS: navigating apple shortcuts app list/menus with the keyboard?
I've written a working shortcut that I run via the spotlight search. It prompts for inputs via a series of list action menus. They all work fine, but on my ipad they seem to be touch only. The keyboard is actually still focused on spotlight search box when it runs.
Do keybinds exist for navigating shortcut menus? or am i running/focusing them wrong somehow?
Here's part of the shortcut that calls "choose from list":

And running the shortcut via spotlight. It's touch/clickable, but I cannot seem to interact with it in any way via the keyboard:

I did test it and was able to navigate the menus (poorly) via full keyboard access. but I'd rather not use it because it interferes with other applications, and there seems to be no quick way to enable/disable it outside manually in the settings app.
